# How can I achieve this "stroked lines" effect?

Tags: 3d, shaders, mesh, graphic-effects, signed-distance-field

I have a collection of arbitrary vertices and edges that are connected, but which do not necessarily form triangles. These vertices and edges mostly fall along a flat plane, but have some height variation. They represent points on terrain with paths between them. You could think of them as overlapping roads, rivers, or a navigation mesh.

I would like to draw them like this:

[image: lines drawn in the way I want]

In this sketch, we see vertices (black) and edges(red) on the left. On the right, we see blue blobs corresponding to the pixels that are within some radius "r" of any vertex or edge. When viewed from the side, the blue areas basically correspond to the "floor" near edges and vertexes.

So far, I have tried to do this just by drawing quads at along every edge with thickness "r", but this doesn't look great because the vertices are all (slightly different) heights (they are positioned on terrain), so the individual quads are visible as overlapping ribbons in 3d space. I also haven't yet looked into how to make smooth miters where the vertices join multiple edges together.

I should mention I'm using glsl for this project, and modern opengl on android.

One thing I've though of doing was "painting" a 2d raster image as viewed from above, and then projecting that down onto the terrain as a texture or light of some kind.

Comment: You mention z-fighting and blending, but in your examples the lines/blobs are all the same colour. Is your actual application drawing these blobs in different colours or with surface textures, or stacking them on top of some background geometry that pokes through occasionally?  Including these details in your question can help us suggest appropriate mitigations.

Comment: This application involves drawing them all with the same color, and occasionally there is other geometry drawn in the scene. I guess by z-fighting I mean that you can see where individual quads have very slightly different heights when viewed from a first person character walking around the scene, so it has the appearance of a bunch of 3d overlapping ribbons.

Comment: Ahhh, that's not quite what "Z-fighting" means in usual gamedev parlance.

Comment: Edited with more details, thanks. Specifically I think I'm wanting to draw this as though it were 2d texture projected onto terrain below the camera, rather than as individual 3d elements.